# Create Responsive Video Grid Without Download Button

Tags: video

I created Responsive Video Grid.
I would like to disable/remove download video button. 
Kindly please help me to solve this problem.
The view is fine, the only problem is the button, I don't want that.
Here is the code I'm trying, as you can see here:

Also on [codepen](https://codepen.io/DODIONE/pen/PoYMNaE?editors=1100)

```css
/* 
Layout: Large Horizontal 
Thumbnail min-width: 260px
Thumbnail max-width: 400px
Layout Tresholds: 
    0 to 200px wide: 2 columns
    201 to 500px wide: 3 columns
    501 to 800px wide: 4 columns
    801px wide and more: 5 columns
*/

body {
  font:12px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#000;
  margin-left: 80px;
  min-width:578px; /* 300 (item's min-width) is 45% of 578 */ 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

p { margin:0px 0; }
a { color:inherit;text-decoration:none; }
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
.right { float:right; }

#bigTitle {
  font-size:24px;
  margin:18px 0;
}
#poweredBy {
  font-size:11px;
}
#poweredBy a {
  color:#000;
}

.videoItem { 
  float:left;
  min-width:260px;
  max-width:400px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) { /* 400 (item's max-width) is 47% of 851 */
  .videoItem { width:48.5%; margin-right:3%; }
  .videoItem:nth-child(2) { margin-right:0; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 201px) and (max-width: 500px) { /* 400 (item's max-width) is 30% of 1250 */
  .videoItem { width:32%; margin-right:2%; }
  .videoItem:nth-child(3) { margin-right:0; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 800px) { /* 400 (item's max-width) is 23% of 1739 */
  .videoItem { width:24%; margin-right:1.3333%; }
  .videoItem:nth-child(4) { margin-right:0; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) { 
  .videoItem { width:19%; margin-right:1.25%; }
  .videoItem:nth-child(5) { margin-right:0; }
}
.videoItem:last-child {
  margin:0;
}
.thumbnail {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
}
.thumbnail img {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.thumbnail:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  Z-index:1;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.videoItem:hover .thumbnail:after {
  opacity:0;
}
.duration {
  position:absolute;
  height:18px;
  z-index:2;
  bottom:5px;
  right:5px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  color:#fff;
  padding:2px 6px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.play {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://static1.dmcdn.net/images/home/play.png.v11b2fefa92a0dc9b);
  height: 36px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -18px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.category {
  font-size:11px;
  margin:2px 0;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#aaa;
}
.category.promoted {
  color:#e09021;
}
.title {
  font-weight:bold;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.title a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0079B8;
}
.author {
  color:#7F7F7F;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<p id="poweredBy" class="right">Powered by <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>
<p id="bigTitle">Recommended Videos</p>
</div>
<div id="list">
<div class="videoItem">
<p class="category">Category</p>
<a href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/Paypal.mp4?2424" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/hijab.jpg?2424" />
<div class="play"></div>
<span class="duration">05:00</span> </a>
<p class="title"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam massa dui, ornare eu porttitor ut, tristique ac tellus.</a></p>
<p class="author"><a href="#">Author</a></p>
</div>
<div class="videoItem">
<p class="category promoted">Promoted</p>
<a href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/Paypal.mp4?2424" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/hijab.jpg?2424" />
<div class="play"></div>
<span class="duration">05:00</span> </a>
<p class="title"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam massa dui, ornare eu porttitor ut, tristique ac tellus.</a></p>
<p class="author"><a href="#">Author</a></p>
</div>
<div class="videoItem">
<p class="category promoted">Promoted</p>
<a href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/Paypal.mp4?2424" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/hijab.jpg?2424" />
<div class="play"></div>
<span class="duration">05:00</span> </a>
<p class="title"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam massa dui, ornare eu porttitor ut, tristique ac tellus.</a></p>
<p class="author"><a href="#">Author</a></p>
</div>
<div class="videoItem">
<p class="category promoted">Promoted</p>
<a href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/Paypal.mp4?2424" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/hijab.jpg?2424" />
<div class="play"></div>
<span class="duration">05:00</span> </a>
<p class="title"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam massa dui, ornare eu porttitor ut, tristique ac tellus.</a></p>
<p class="author"><a href="#">Author</a></p>
</div>
<div class="videoItem">
<p class="category promoted">Promoted</p>
<a href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/Paypal.mp4?2424" class="thumbnail"> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1872/1855/files/hijab.jpg?2424" />
<div class="play"></div>
<span class="duration">05:00</span> </a>
<p class="title"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam massa dui, ornare eu porttitor ut, tristique ac tellus.</a></p>
<p class="author"><a href="#">Author</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I disable or remove the download button?

Comment: *I would like to disable/remove download video button*, so, what you have tried..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the `download` button on the video you will need to add the `controlsList="nodownload"` option to your player. In your current version you are just linking directly to the mp4 source, so the browser is displaying it using the defaults

eg:

```
<video id="video" controls controlsList="nodownload" autoplay playsinline preload="auto" poster="my_video_poster.jpg" loop muted>
  <source src="my_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you the answer, I try add controlsList="nodownload" but still didn't work, maybe I have mistaken to put it in my HTML, could you help me please, where I should put it. If you don't mind, please give me example to put it in one of my HTML video above..

Comment: at the moment you don't have a `<video>` tag on your page, you're just linking through to an MP4. you will need to actually set the source to the selected video, or use the code snippet above instead of the `<a href>...<img>... </a>` replacing the poster with your img and the src with your video