# How to remove download video option from an iframe

Tags: html, video, iframe

I am currently using Linux to solve this and using apache to view it on my windows system.
It only happens in Linux as in windows. If I run this code, it works as intended, and it also works in the Linux browser. But when I try to run it in windows browser from Linux, it shows the 'download option.'

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('video').attr('controlsList', 'nodownload');
});
```

```css
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  overflow: hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="Recordings/abc.webm" target="video">Session 1 </a> </li>
<div id="frame" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <iframe id="frame-id" style="height:89vh;width:100%;" name="video" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <video autoplay playsinline style="pointer-events: none;">
      <source src="Recordings/abc.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Output showing the download option
[image]

Comment: Iframes have src, whatever you put inside the iframe tags are only shown if the browser does not support iframes

Comment: your controlslist should be on the `<video>` tag, not the `<iframe>`, also not sure why you are wrapping the video in an iframe? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194047/create-responsive-video-grid-without-download-button/58195308#58195308 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507905/html5-video-player-controls-in-chrome-three-dots-on-the-right-open-blank-scree/54508335#54508335

Answer (score 0):

### iframe x video

A Video element allows you to add media to your event page by pasting the HTML embed code or a YouTube or Vimeo URL link. **You have the option to hide any video controls like pause, sound options, settings. etc.** You also have the option to set the video to loop.

Video elements are more responsive and can be resized across devices like Phones and tablets.

An iframe element, short for the inline frame, is an HTML element that allows an external webpage to be embedded in an HTML document. **There are no options to hide controls** or loop iframes.

*link: https://support.splashthat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037963911-What-s-the-difference-between-Iframe-elements-and-Video-elements-*

As an alternative instead of using `<iframe>` use just the `video` tag, e.g.:

```
<video
  allow="fullscreen"
  frameBorder="0"
  width="100%"
  height="700"
  controls
  controlsList="nodownload"
>
  <source :src="<SOME URL TO VIDEO>" />
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {

display:none;

}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {

overflow:hidden;

}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {

width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */

}

audio::-internal-media-controls-download-button {

display:none !important;

}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {

overflow:hidden !important;

}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {

width: calc(100% + 30px) !important;

}
```

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/disable+download+video+in+iframe

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but it still shows the download option.